# How to handle Daylight saving time in laravel/php?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, dst

In the following code, i update or create a post based on the values that i receive from an api,

```
                  $this->channel->posts()->updateOrCreate([
                        'identifier' => $post->getId(),
                    ],
                        [
                            'title' => $post->getTitle(),
                            'description' => $post->getDescription(),
                            'posted_at' => $post->getPublishedAt(),
                        ]);
```

In the instance where posted_at = '2023-03-26 02:36:24', i get this error :

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2023-03-26 02:36:24' for column 'posted_at' at row 1 (SQL: update table_name set posted_at = 2023-03-26 02:36:24, table_name.updated_at = 2023-11-16 10:14:52 where id = 934579)`

Which happens because the datetime value falls in the DST, this is the original format the datetime value was returned from the api "2023-03-26T02:36:24+0000" and the server timezone is "UTC"

the setPublishedAt function parses the value as below :

```
    public function setPublishedAt($publishedAt)
    {
        if (is_numeric($publishedAt)) {
            $this->publishedAt = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($publishedAt);
        } else {
            $this->publishedAt = Carbon::parse($publishedAt);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

but it doesn't handle the issue.

Comment: Normally you would handle all dates-times internally, that is "inside your program", in UTC. Since none of the code in your question is responsible for output there should be no problem. Unless you use another timezone on your server?

Comment: It sounds like your MySQL timezone isn't UTC. You'll probably need to set it in a query before inserting, or see if you can change it overall.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware both my PHP server and MySQL server have UTC timezone, and the data from the facebook api comes in  UTC timezone : 2023-03-26T02:36:24+0000.

Comment: Backgrounder: [Does UTC Observe Daylight Saving Time?](https://www.worldtimeserver.com/learn/does-utc-observe-daylight-saving-time/) In short: _The switch to daylight saving time does not affect UTC_.

Comment: Try  `'posted_at' => $post->getPublishedAt()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Comment: `update table_name set posted_at = 2023-03-26 02:36:24` seems perfectly valid.  What column type is posted_at?